# AcquireTokenAsync returns 401(Unauthorized) for usercredentials in graph client library

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, adal

My code snippet :

```cs
AuthenticationContext authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(aadTokenIssuerUri);

UserCredential userCredentials = new UserPasswordCredential(username, password);

AuthenticationResult authenticationResult = authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(
                resources,
                clientId,
                userCredentials)
                .GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

This function always returns "The request body must contain the following parameter: 'client_assertion' or 'client_secret'" and "Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized)". I am trying to authenticate an Azure AD user.

Comment: Hi, now I am getting this "The user or administrator has not consented to use the application with ID. Send an interactive authorization request for this user and resource.{Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AdalServiceException}"  and token is NULL.

Comment: In api permission, click `Grant admin consent for xxx` button. If you are not a tenant admin, you cannot give admin consent.

Comment: Any update now?

Comment: Glad to hear that. And you can accept it as answer to close this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the app that registered in aad and click `Authentication`> `Advanced settings`, set **application as a public client**. That should stop Azure from requiring a client secret or client assertion.

[image]

After that, in Manifest `allowPublicClient` will be `true`.

Comment: Thanks ! this solution did not work for me. still token is NULL

Comment: Use `var token = authenticationResult.AccessToken; ` to get the accesstoken.